# How to use Hash SHA in Xamarin

Tags: c#, hash, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sha

I want to hash a String with C# in Xamarin.
Normally I'd use:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public string SHA512StringHash(String input)
{
    SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed();
    // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
    byte[] data = shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
    // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
    // and create a string.
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    // Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
    // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    // Return the hexadecimal string.
    input = sBuilder.ToString();
    return (input);
}
```

But in Xamarin I don't seem able to include this library.
Is there a way to include this library or an alternative to easily hash a Password?

Comment: http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512/

Comment: I am able to include this liblary on Xamarin.Android and to use SHA1,SHA512 etc, maybe you miss a reference?

Comment: Are you using a portable class library?

Comment: I´m using Xamarins.Forms Portable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution,
i was trying to create this class in the Forms Solution, but in this Solution
`using System.Security.Cryptography;`
is not available.
In the iOS and Android Solution it is available.
So i implemented an Interface in the Forms Solution and used the Method in the iOS and Android Solution.

Answer (score 1):

System.Security.Cryptography is not available in PCL projects. You could use pclcontrib nuget to have System.Security.Cryptography in PCL project.
http://pclcontrib.codeplex.com

Comment: Could not install package 'PclContrib.Platform 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: Does 'PclContrib.Platform 1.0.0' compatible with xamarin forms PCL? I cannot add it.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this wouldn't work. I created a sample project to test it out and it works perfectly. The only thing i had to do is add a reference to:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
```

Add this line to the top of your file and it should do the trick. Or right click on the object that isn't being recognized and let XamStudio or VS solve it for you by resolving it like this:

[image]

Comment: what theme are you using?